# Updating stroke size dynamically for array of shapes in Java

Tags: java, paint, shapes, stroke

i have created a simple program in Java for painting Graphic primitives (Lines,Rectangles,Ellipses,etc.).The shapes are drawn on the screen with dragging the mouse and stored into an array of Shapes,so i have added a slider for getting the stroke size (from 1 to 20 with 1 being default value) dynamically,but it updates all the shapes that are previously drawn as well.

//NOTE1: Graphics2D graph; is defined in the class extending JFrame

//NOTE2: strokeSize value is dynamically changing with the slider

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
            {

                    graph = (Graphics2D)g;

                    graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                    graph.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeSize));

for (Shape currentShape : shapes)
                    {
                        graph.setPaint(strokeCounter.next());

                        graph.draw(currentShape);

                        graph.setPaint(fillCounter.next());

                        graph.fill(currentShape);
                    }


//What follows are If statements for choosing a shape 

//and actual methods for drawing them...
```

So my question is:How to update the strokeSize,but only for shapes currently being drawn?

Comment: Where the `strokeSize` is defined?

Comment: In the class extending JFrame before the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Store the stroke size along with the shape. Set the stroke size before issuing the draw command.

Comment: You mean to put: 
graph.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeSize));
above 
graph.draw(currentShape); 
?

I already tried that,but it still updates the strokeSize for the already drawn shapes as well.

Comment: You must be putting it in the wrong place then. Make sure it is inside the loop but before the draw.

Comment: Well,
yes,it is inside the loop,but still doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add `graph.setStroke(new BasicStroke(currentShape.getStrokeSize()));` before `graph.draw(currentShape);`

You'll need to add a property called `StrokeSize` to your `Shape` class.

Comment: Shape is not a class.I have an array of shapes: ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

Comment: @user3086760 You won't be able to use it with `ArrayList` if it's not a class. I think you need to define a new class which will contain your `Shape` and its stroke size.